# How to close all open forms/reports etc. when a button is pressed to log out?

Tags: vba, ms-access, authentication, logout

I'm making a database for an assignment.

When you log in it checks whether the user is an admin. An admin has access to different forms.

My logout button opens up the login form and they can't do anything else until they sign in.

If an admin hasn't closed their admin-specific forms when they log out then a non-admin can log in onto their account and the forms the admin failed to close will still be open.

How do I close all open forms/reports etc. when a button is pressed to log out?

Comment: Logout should be closing the front-end.You can check user.rights at`Form_Activate` (and close form if no access-right) to be sure non-admins can't access them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are closing forms during the loop, and therefore removing them from the Forms collection, this sort of loop is needed:

```
Public Sub Logout()

    Dim F As Access.Form
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Loop all open forms, from last to first, to avoid problems due to closing forms
    ' (removing them from the Forms collection) in the loop
    For i = Forms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Set F = Forms(i)
        ' Close all forms except the login form
        If F.Name <> "frmLogin" Then
            DoCmd.Close acForm, F.Name
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

And of course the same for the `Reports` collection.

---

In general, an easier way to loop collections is with `For Each`, but this doesn't work if collection members are removed during the loop.
Thanks Blackbath and DecoMartins for pointing that out.

```
    Dim varF As Variant
    ' Loop all open forms
    For Each varF In Forms
        If varF.Name <> "frmLogin" Then
            ' Do something with varF
        End If
    Next varF
```

Comment: Ah this is almost working! When I login it opens up the main menu, I click logout and it closes the main menu and opens the login form. That's great. But then if I have a load of forms and reports open and click logout it'll close some but not others. And it's not the same ones each time either.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: The first code example will not work as expected. The Applications.Forms collection changes as the form is closed and as the collection is altered by the DoCmd the For Next statement is working with a now obsolete pointer, leaving you with some open forms.

Comment: You are correct @DecoMartins, the 2nd version should have been the primary one.